# best way to handle matrix of dots in iOS

Tags: ios, matrix

I need to handle a matrix of dots in an iphone application to be able to draw lines between the dots. Here dots are a collection of CGPoint. What is the best way of dealing with such kind of matrix? I would like to create the array/matrix in such a way that I can access all the neighbours of a given point. After a lot of googling I found Accelerate.framework that is also handleing such kind of stuff but it seems to be much complex.
Any idea on this?
Thanks
Arnieterm

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the data storage or the drawing?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a data structure in such a way that each dot will have information about its adjoining neighbours and this linked collection must be efficient. More precisely I want to create a Matrix class

Answer (score 0):

A matrix class should be relatively easy to make. If the size of the matrix is constant, you can easily use a c array. Using some simple math you can access any element in the matrix in constant time.

element at column c and row r: x = matrix[ r * NUM_COLUMNS + c ];

element above element at index i: matrix[ i - NUM_COLUMNS ];
element below element at index i: matrix[ i + NUM_COLUMNS ];
element to the right of element at index i: matrix[ i + 1 ];
element to the left of element at index i: matrix[ i - 1 ];

depending on what you want to do at the edges you may have to use some if statement or possibly modulus operators if you want to wrap around the matrix.